# The connection to the sever localhost:8080 was refused - Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to deploy a GitHub repo using Kubernetes. From the debugging that i've done, I found that when I installed `kubect1`, the  `$Home/.kube/config` file missing.

When I try to run this command:

```
kubect1 create -f tracee/deploy/kubernetes/trace-postee/tracee.yaml
```

This is what it results to:

> "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
> specify the right host or port?"

There's no config file. Does anyone know how I can generate one in Ubuntu?

I've attached some images for context:

[image: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Cqv.png)]

[image: [Image 2]()]

Comment: Did you install Kubernetes on you Ubuntu machine? It seems that you only installed the kubernetes client(kubectl). Try installing a Kubernetes instance in your machine with something like minikube. Just search on  google something like "install minikube in ubuntu", there's tons of guides and howto's. Have a nice day 